# Unhandled promise rejection Error: "Can't connect to twilsock"

Tags: twilio-programmable-chat

I go through [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/tutorials/chat-application-php-laravel)

```
Unhandled promise rejection Error: "Can't connect to twilsock"

http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/v3.0/twilio-chat.min.js:204
    t http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/v3.0/twilio-chat.min.js:204
    t http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/v3.0/twilio-chat.min.js:204
    value http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/v3.0/twilio-chat.min.js:204
    value http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/v3.0/twilio-`enter code here`chat.min.js:204
```

I'm using laravel 5.8.*
reference from
https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/tutorials/chat-application-php-laravel

> Unhandled promise rejection Error: "Can't connect to twilsock"

Comment: Where you able to find a solution?

Comment: Found any solutions?

Comment: Ya, I used this example https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/twiliochat-laravel
Please refer this.